# Subscribing to an Observable by showing a form does not draw the control

Tags: c#, winforms, system.reactive, reactive, filesystemwatcher

I have an Observable wrapper around a FileSystemWatcher.

```
public readonly FileSystemWatcher Watcher;
public ObservableFileSystemWatcher(FileSystemWatcher watcher)
{
    if (watcher is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(watcher));

    Watcher = watcher;

    Changed = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(h => Watcher.Changed += h, h => Watcher.Changed -= h)
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

    Renamed = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<RenamedEventHandler, RenamedEventArgs>(h => Watcher.Renamed += h, h => Watcher.Renamed -= h)
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

    Deleted = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(h => Watcher.Deleted += h, h => Watcher.Deleted -= h)
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

    Errors = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<ErrorEventHandler, ErrorEventArgs>(h => Watcher.Error += h, h => Watcher.Error -= h)
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

    Created = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(h => Watcher.Created += h, h => Watcher.Created -= h)
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs);
}
```

Said Observable is observed in an ApplicationContext (tray program) like this:

```
private void Watchers_Start()
{
    _filesystemwatchers?.Clear();
    foreach (var path in _pathsToCheck)
    {
        try
        {
            ObservableFileSystemWatcher fsw = new ObservableFileSystemWatcher(c => { c.Path = path; c.IncludeSubdirectories = false; });
            fsw.Created
                .Where(_ => _.ChangeType is WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
                .Select(_ => _.FullPath)
                .Where(_ => !Path.GetFileName(_).StartsWith("~"))
                .Where(File.Exists)
                .Where(_ => ((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(_lastFilesystem_Event)).TotalSeconds > _minDelayInSec))
                .DistinctUntilChanged()
                .Subscribe(Filesystem_Event);

            fsw.Errors.Subscribe(x => LogMsg($"ObservableFileSystemWatcher().Error {x.GetException().Message}", true));

            _filesystemwatchers.Add(fsw);
            fsw.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception exc) when (LogMsg(exc)) { }
    }
}
```

And the method called on every event, is:

```
private void Filesystem_Event(string flPath)
{
try
{
    if (_playSound)
        PlaySound();

    if (_openPopup)
        OpenPopup($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}{Environment.NewLine} blahblah", flPath);
}
catch (Exception ex) when (LogMsg(ex)) { }
}
```

Which in turn calls the following to show a Form to the user as a notification (PopupForm is just a regular Form):

```
private void OpenPopup(string message, string filepath = "")
{
    if (message is null) message = string.Empty;

    LogMsg($"OpenPopup({message})");
    _popupWindow = new PopupForm();
    _popupWindow.Show();
}
```

Well, if from the ApplicationContext's Tray Icon I right click and choose to show a test notification, it works flawlessly. It's just a regular C# event.

```
 _notifyIcon.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[]
{
    new MenuItem("Riavvia", new EventHandler(RestartEventHandler)),
    new MenuItem("Configura", new EventHandler(ShowConfig)),
    new MenuItem("Test Audio", new EventHandler(PlayTestSound)),
    new MenuItem("Test Popup", new EventHandler(OpenTestPopup)),
    new MenuItem("Test Email", new EventHandler(SendTestEmail)),
    new MenuItem("Test Errore", new EventHandler(SendTestException)),
    new MenuItem("Esci", new EventHandler(Exit))
});

/// which in turn calls 
private void OpenTestPopup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenPopup("TEST POPUP");
}
```

Everything works fine!

[image: normally_drawn_form]

**But if it's the method I observe the FileSystemWatcher on to call the OpenPopup method (on filesystem events), the form just won't draw completely.**

[image: abnormally_drawn_form]

I sense a SynchronizationContext issue, or a deadlock issue, or maybe both.
Probably the Observable isn't returning fully until the sequence is complete? *The above does not happen if I choose to show a plain MessageBox, which is baffling me.*

I already tried:

- forcing the ObservableFileSystemWatcher on a different Scheduler
- passing the ApplicationContext's SynchronizationContext to the ObservableFileSystemWatcher
- forcing the ObservableFileSystemWatcher to run on the Scheduler.CurrentThread

**edit**
I understand what Panagiotis Kanavos is trying to say, to *observe* on a different thread and then *subscribe* in the UI thread. My problem is that an ApplicationContext is no UI, it just can launch forms (it's a tray icon).

If I refactor my ObservableFileSystemWatcher in such a way,

```
public ObservableFileSystemWatcher(FileSystemWatcher watcher)
{
    if (watcher is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(watcher));

    Watcher = watcher;

    Changed = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(h => Watcher.Changed += h, h => Watcher.Changed -= h)
        .ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs);
    // blabla
}
```

And observe it like this

```
.SubscribeOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
```

I (rightfully so) get an InvalidOperationException *"The current thread has no Dispatcher associated with it."* because ApplicationContext is not a WinForm.

Comment: Rx uses a single thread to for both observers and subscribers. This makes sense as its main job is to process event streams, not act as an alternative to `async/await`. Use `ObserveOn` and `SubscribeOn` to specify different threads

Comment: If the Form was being drawn on another thread, I'd get a cross thread exception. It is also not being used as an async/await alternative, I just need to manage a stream of Events, which is what Observable is for. I already tried to pass the main Application's Context to the Observable and ObserveOn that, but the result is the same.

Comment: You need to *observe* on another thread and subscribe on the UI thread

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos see my edit please! And thanks for your contribution so far.

Comment: @SimoneF - You need to add an `.ObserveOn(reference_to_your_form_or_a_ui_element)` before your `.Subscribe`. Often `ObserveOn(this)` works.

Comment: @Enigmativity my problem is that in my case I am observing from an ApplicationContext, which in turn launches the form that hangs. Not from another Form!